# Angular 2 test with Jasmine and Typescript produces hundreds of d.ts errors and no test result

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jasmine

I am doing my first use of Jasmine testing by following Google's instructions at:  http://devdocs.io/angular~2_typescript/guide/testing  I am using Angular 2.1.2, Typescript 2.0.7, and other support components are also up to date. My app.component.spec.ts file is in the same directory/folder as my app.component.ts file. Atom Typescript says I have no errors in any file. I have run the following command on core-js, jasmine, and node to have current d.ts files for them.

```
npm install @types/jasmine --save-dev
```

My app.component.spec.ts has the code from Angular2's QuickStart file of the same name, plus the first test from the devdocs guide, namely:

```
describe('1st tests', () => {
  it('true is true', () => expect(true).toBe(true));
});
```

I expected this test to be true, and the Quickstart test to be false (because I'm not building the Quickstart app). Neither message appeared.

Instead, I got **hundreds** of lines of error messages in the Node console.  Most of them seem to be about d.ts errors in several support components, e.g., Angular2, core-js, angular/material, hammerjs, typings/global/node/index.d.ts, and others. I have no idea what's going on.

What is the cause of error messages for commonly used components? What further information do I need to post to make this solvable?

Some examples of my error messages are:

```
node_modules/@angular/core/src/util/decorators.d.ts(11,5): error TS2411: Property 'extends' of type 'Type<any> | undefined' is not assignable to string index type 'Function | any[] | Type<any>'.

node_modules/@angular/forms/src/model.d.ts(544,9): error TS2459: Type '{ onlySelf?: boolean | undefined; } | undefined' has no property 'onlySelf' and no string index signature.

node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/dom/dom_renderer.d.ts(25,22): error TS2420: Class 'DomRenderer' incorrectly implements interface 'Renderer'.
  Types of property 'animate' are incompatible.
    Type '(element: any, startingStyles: AnimationStyles | undefined, keyframes: (AnimationKeyframe | undef...' is not assignable to type '(element: any, startingStyles: AnimationStyles, keyframes: AnimationKeyframe[], duration: number,...'.

typings/globals/typescript/index.d.ts(1289,9): error TS2411: Property 'charset' of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to string index type 'string | number | boolean'.

typings/globals/core-js/index.d.ts(1501,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'export='.

typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(570,22): error TS2320: Interface 'Server' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Server'.
  Named property 'once' of types 'EventEmitter' and 'Server' are not identical.
typings/globals/node/index.d.ts(570,22): error TS2320: Interface 'Server' cannot simultaneously extend types 'EventEmitter' and 'Server'.

node_modules/@angular/material/core/gestures/MdGestureConfig.d.ts(2,22): error TS2415: Class 'MdGestureConfig' incorrectly extends base class 'HammerGestureConfig'.
  Types of property 'buildHammer' are incompatible.
    Type '(element: HTMLElement) => HammerManager' is not assignable to type '(element: HTMLElement) => HammerInstance'.
```

Comment: This blog post about ambient type definitions, http://blog.mgechev.com/2016/03/28/ambient-type-definitions-duplicate-identifier-typescript-fix/  indicates that at least some of the problem is conflicting d.ts files. I followed instructions and removed @type files for core-js,node, hammerjs an jasmine. Apparently Typescript 2 has better d.ts for them. I'm left with 30+ errors in typings/globals/typescript/index.d.ts and about 10 errors in @angular/forms/src/model.d.ts  These don't look like the files can be removed.  Any ideas?

Comment: OK, the @angular/forms errors are caused by Angular 2 code. The fault is reported in Issue #11898, and "will be fixed soon". Lets see if I can figure out typings/globals/typescript errors.

Comment: OK, the typings/globals/typescript/index.d.ts errors were caused by a file of that path. I installed it a week ago from some tutorial that said to use @typings/name to get d.ts for several components. Seems it was out of date, and seems that Typescript 2.1.1 has d.ts files for all I need. The typings global install has all I need, I guess, because everything is working.  The remaining few errors are Angular 2 bugs. What a time sink this has been.